# [ROS2][rclcpp][services] Service not being created

Tags: ros, ros2, rclcpp, dds

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am attempting to write a ROS2 SetBool Service.

I am getting no compile-time errors, and I am getting to a logger message that is placed after I call the `create_service` method.

Even after this, **the service is not advertised when I call `ros2 service list`.**

- I am on Ubuntu 20.04, Foxy, x86
  (don't think that is relevant).

The constructor / destructor:

```
// Minimal Example

#include <memory.h>

#include "my_test_robot/main.hpp"

#include "rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp"
#include "std_srvs/srv/set_bool.hpp"


MinimalExampleNode::MinimalExampleNode()
: Node("minimal_example_node")
{
  rclcpp::Service<std_srvs::srv::SetBool>::SharedPtr set_bool_service_ =
    this->create_service<std_srvs::srv::SetBool>(
      "set_bool",
      std::bind(&MinimalExampleNode::setBoolServiceCallback,
      this,
      std::placeholders::_1,
      std::placeholders::_2,
      std::placeholders::_3));
    RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "Service ready");
}

MinimalExampleNode::~MinimalExampleNode() {}
```

The Callback., This is not even entered as the service does not appear to be advertised.

```
void MinimalExampleNode::setBoolServiceCallback(
  const std::shared_ptr<rmw_request_id_t> request_header,
  const std::shared_ptr<std_srvs::srv::SetBool::Request> request,
  const std::shared_ptr<std_srvs::srv::SetBool::Response> response)
{
  (void)request_header;
  bool ready_state = request->data;
  bool success = false;
  if (ready_state) {
    RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "Ready recieved");
    success = true;
  } else {
    RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "Not Ready recieved");
      }
      response->success = success;
    }
```

The main function. This is the only part in my head that is slightly different than the example tutorial.

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
  rclcpp::init(argc, argv);
  rclcpp::spin(std::make_shared<MinimalExampleNode>());
  rclcpp::shutdown();
  return 0;
}
```

I am not sure what is going wrong, as even my minimal example is exhibiting this behavior. Does it have something to do with the way I am spinning the node?

**Update**

I think this might be a DDS issue? The above was on FastRTPS ... but when I switch to CycloneDDS
`export RMW_IMPLEMENTATION=rmw_cyclonedds_cpp`
the issue goes away? Not sure if that is a bandaid or the proper solution.

**Update 2**
Switching to cycloneDDS only helped solve service discovery. Calling the service was still not possible using a minmal service client, nor `ros2 service call`.

When the service is created in `main`, then the service is both discoverable **and** callable. Is it something about creating the service in the constructor that I am doing incorrectly?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/368193/%5Bros2%5D%5Brclcpp%5D%5Bservices%5D-service-not-being-created/) by [vinny](https://answers.ros.org/users/52902/vinny/) on ROS Answers with karma: 291 on 2020-12-21

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem is you're saving the output of `create_service` in a local variable only. When the constructor ends, the local variable is destroyed along with the service. It should work if you instead store it in a member variable of `MinimalExampleNode`.

---

Originally posted by [jdlangs](https://answers.ros.org/users/2128/jdlangs/) with karma: 971 on 2020-12-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vinny](https://answers.ros.org/users/52902/vinny/) on 2020-12-23**:
good point. that was the issue. what a learning opportunity for me. Thanks for the catch!